# how to fill out the table in Jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug

I have an array of objects

```
[{ name: Test1, phoneNumb: 123, email: abc }, {name: Test2, phoneNumb: 321, email: cba}, ...]
```

how to fill out a table of these values in Jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AngularJS try this:

```
table
    thead
        tr
            th Name
            th Phone number
            th Email
    tbody
        tr(ng-repeat='item in items')
            td item.name
            td item.phoneNumb
            td item.email
```

And in your controller assign the items collection like this:

```
$scope.items = [{ name: "Test1", phoneNumb: 123, email: "abc" }, {name: "Test2", phoneNumb: 321, email: "cba"}];
```

If you don't use AngularJS repeat each `tr` tag manually.

```
table
        thead
            tr
                th Name
                th Phone number
                th Email
        tbody
```

and javascript function:

```
function fillTable() {
    var array = [{ name: "Test1", phoneNumb: 123, email: "abc" }, {name: "Test2", phoneNumb: 321, email: "cba"}];

    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();

        var name = row.insertCell(0);
        var number = row.insertCell(1);
        var email = row.insertCell(3);

        name.innerHTML = array[i].name;
        number.innerHTML = array[i].phoneNumb;
        email.innerHTML = array[i].email;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont use angular. Only jade